# How to sign a Wine Winery package on MacOS?

Tags: code-signing, wine, code-signing-certificate

I've created a Wine Winery package on MacOS for our Windows Application.
Double-clicking the package, starts the windows application properly on MacOS. This works fine.

We distribute this Wine Package via a kind of 'dropbox' where customers can pick it up.
When our customers have downloaded the package, and want to start it, they get a dialog the with following message: ***"OUR PRODUCT is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the bin".***

Example:

[image]

I know there are workarounds (manual steps that the user can do to force the application to start, but this is not the way we want to go).
I assume the problem is that the package is not signed?!
As there is no option in the Wine Winery application to sign the package during the "baking" process, the signing probably needs to happen afterwards.

Any idea which steps I need to follow to properly sign the Wine Package (we have a company certificate but until now I only used it on windows to sign applications).

**Update**

When I use the following command line:

```
codesign --sign <common identity name> --deep --force /Users/<Username>/Signing/MyPackage.app
```

I get the following error:

> /Users//Signing/MyPackage.app: unsealed contents present in the bundle root.

It seems that you receive this message when there are files on the root that are not part of the contents folder.
But the Wine Winery package generation generates the app folder structure like this...

**Update 2**

When I verify the Wine Package that I, tried to, sign(ed)... and that generated the unsealed contents warning, I receive another, totally different warning.

To verify I used:

```
codesign --deep --verify --strict --verbose=2 /Users/<Username>/Signing/MyPackage.app
```

I get the following warning for this:

> /Users//Signing/MyPackage.app: code has no resources but signature indicates they must be present

I lost track at the moment. Someone any ideas?